# The image background can not fit the height of body content container in email template?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have problem with the image background for email template. As you see the screenshots, I want the email in Outlook for Window 7/10 will display the same as Outlook for MacOS. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. I try many times but cannot figure out the reason why the body container always has the space between it and footer container. Please help me to solve this problem! My code is below
:([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTi29.jpg)

```html
  <!-- BODY START // -->
                <tr>
                    <td>    
                          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;" role="presentation">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" mc:repeatable="" role="presentation" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td background="http://test.agency-spring.digital/Bekreftelses/background-image.png" style="background-image:url(http://test.agency-spring.digital/Bekreftelses/background-image.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size:cover;background-position: center center;" bgcolor="#d1dce0" valign="top">
                                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
                                            <v:fill type="tile" src="http://test.agency-spring.digital/Bekreftelses/background-image.png" style="background-size:cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;" color="#d1dce0" />
                                                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                    <![endif]-->                                  

                                        <!-- test -->
                                        <div>
                                            <div style="">
                                            <table role="presentation" class="templateContainer" width="600" style="width:600px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                            <tr>
                                            <td height="" align="center">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <!-- divider -->
                                                            <td width="600" padding="55px 30px 0"
                                                                style="width:100%;padding:55px 30px 0;border-spacing: 0;">
                                                                <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="border-spacing: 0;">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="42" height="6" style="background:#e40532; height:6px;width:42px;">
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td width="42" height="6" style="height:6px;width:42px;font-size:0; line-height:6px;">
                                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <!-- end -->
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="row-1-column" mc:repeatable="" mc:variant="Row-1-column">
                                                            <td width="600" padding="5px 30px 0 30px"
                                                                style="width:100%;padding:5px 30px 0 30px;">
                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"
                                                                    width="100%">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <div mc:edit="row1column__texta">
                                                                                    <h1>Tak for din bestilling!</h1>
                                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                                                                    <p>{{Name}}</p>
                                                                                    <p>{{Address}}</p>
                                                                                    <p>Tlf. {{Phone}}</p>
                                                                                    <p>Reg.nr.: {{CarReg}}</p>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="row-1-column" mc:repeatable="" mc:variant="Row-1-column">
                                                            <td width="600" padding="25px 30px 0 30px"
                                                                style="width:100%;padding:25px 30px 0 30px;">
                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"
                                                                    width="100%">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <div mc:edit="row1column__texta">
                                                                                    <p padding="20px 0" color="#e40532"
                                                                                        style="color:#e40532;font-weight: bolder;padding:20px 0 10px;">
                                                                                        Du har bestilt følgende:</p>
                                                                                    <p padding="20px 0" color="#e40532"
                                                                                        style="font-weight: bolder;padding:20px 0 10px; ">
                                                                                        {{OrderLines}}</p>
                                                                                    <p padding="20px 0" color="#e40532"
                                                                                        style="font-weight: bolder;padding:20px 0 10px;">
                                                                                        {{Services}}</p>
                    
                                                                                    <p>Din bookede tid:<p>
                                                                                    <p padding="0" color="#e40532"
                                                                                        style="font-weight: bolder;padding:0;">
                                                                                        {{BookingTime}}
                                                                                        <span style="font-weight:normal"> hos
                                                                                        </span><span>{{Department}}</span></p>
                    
                                                                                    <p padding="20px 0" style="padding:20px 0 10px;">Kontakt
                                                                                        din afdeling, hvis du vil &aelig;ndre eller aflyse
                                                                                        din booking.</p>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="row-2-column" mc:repeatable="" mc:variant="Row-2-column">
                                                            <td width="600" padding="55px 30px 0" style="width:100%;padding:55px 30px 0;"
                                                                align="left">
                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left"
                                                                    style="width: 100%;">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td width="270" style="width:50%;" align="left">
                                                                                <table>
                                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <td>
                                                                                                <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="18" height="4" style="background:#e40532; height:4px;width:18px;">
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                                        <td width="18" height="4" style="height:4px;width:18px;font-size:0; line-height:4px;">
                                                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                </table>
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <td>
                                                                                                <h2 padding="0 0 20px"
                                                                                                    style="padding:0 0 20px;">Vi glæder os til<br> at servicere din bil
                                                                                                </h2>
                                                                                                <p style="line-height: 150%;">
                                                                                                    Hvis du har spørgsmål - eller hvis der
                                                                                                    er noget, der ikke stemmer, så
                                                                                                    ring til os på <span
                                                                                                        style="font-weight: bolder;">tlf. 7615 3000</span></p>
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td width="270" style="width:50%;" padding="0">                                                                            
                                                                                <table width="270" style="width:100%;" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 100%;width:270px;">
                                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <td>
                                                                                                <img width="270" style="max-width:100%; width:270px;height: auto;" src="http://test.agency-spring.digital/Bekreftelses/S%C3%B8ren.png" alt="Soren" />
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                                </table>                                                                     
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                </v:textbox>
                                            </v:fill>
                                        </v:rect>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>                            
                </tr>
                <!-- // BODY END -->
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your actual problem? I ran a test of your code on Email on Acid but I'm seeing different problems from what you describe. https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/YUhtABvhQOQi7h6ZhbYacD8NyZqivb1mPn4LAlzj3cikz/list

Comment: @HTeuMeuLeu, this link below is my full HTML code for this email. Your render has problem because it is just a part of my code.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10gwYYB3qaMcRwL0W3qclEpiXMCZ0zduz/view?usp=sharing
Please help me to solve this issue, because I try many ways but cannot fixed :(

And this is my problem I have with my code. This screenshot is Outlook 2007 in Window 10
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gW99dX7cu3CN4a635qEkPDmmTQidHuto/view?usp=sharing
Thanks a lot for your kind help!!!!